# LINQ to load specific XML data based on values

Tags: xml, linq, select

Maybe someone can help with a problem I have. I've got this XML data:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data>
<header>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <date>2013-04-02</date>
    <filedate>2013-04-02</filedate>
</header>
<value>
    <TypeId>67772764</TypeId>
    <ServiceID>GN1600</ServiceID>
    <EvbAsof>2013-04-02</EvbAsof>
    <Rating>2</Rating>
    <AdditionalColumns>
        <Name>EvbAvg</Name>
        <Value>7.29495</Value>
    </AdditionalColumns>
    <AdditionalColumns>
        <Name>EvbHigh</Name>
        <Value>12.46</Value>
    </AdditionalColumns>
    <AdditionalColumns>
        <Name>EvbLow</Name>
        <Value>2.88563</Value>
    </AdditionalColumns>
    <AdditionalColumns>
        <Name>EvbBench</Name>
        <Value>1.86241</Value>
    </AdditionalColumns>
</value>
```

...


...

I need to extract the following data, as a set, for each node:

- Date from header node
- TypeID
- ServiceID
- Rating
- EvbAvg value from AditionalColumns
- EvbBench value from AditionalColumns

I managed to get TypeID, ServiceID and Rating, but I just can't figure out how to get the date from the header and EvbAvg and EvbBench from AditionalColumns nodes all in same query.
This is my code so far:

```
    var ServiceDesc = from c in XElement.Load("download.xml").Elements("value")
                       select new
                       {
                           TypeID = c.Element("TypeId").Value,
                           ServiceID = c.Element("ServiceID").Value,
                           Rating = c.Element("Rating").Value
                       }
```

If anyone can help me with this, I'll be inifinitely grateful.
many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a single `header` element and a single `value` one, there's probably little purpose in accessing them as a collection (and if there are multiple instances of each, how do we match them?).

You could simply try something as follows:

```cs
var doc = XElement.Load("download.xml");
var header = doc.Elements("header").Single();
var val = doc.Elements("value").Single();

var serviceDesc = new
{
   Date = DateTime.Parse(header.Element("date").Value,
                         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
   TypeID = val.Element("TypeId").Value,
   ServiceID = val.Element("ServiceID").Value,
   Rating = val.Element("Rating").Value,
   EbvAvg = val.Descendants("AdditionalColumns")
               .Where(node => node.Descendants("Name").Single().Value == "EvbAvg")
               .Select(node => node.Descendants("Value").Single().Value)
               .Single(),
   EbvBench = val.Descendants("AdditionalColumns")
                 .Where(node => node.Descendants("Name").Single().Value == "EvbBench")
                 .Select(node => node.Descendants("Value").Single().Value)
                 .Single()                
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I actually have one HEADER and multiple VALUE elements. It also turns out that some XML files will be missing some of the elements (bar HEADER) so I need a validation rule to insert "No Data" in the result for missing elements. It becomes more and more difficult. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to get the supplier of the files to change the format in a more friendly way. Thanks to everyone!